# How to show, in Django, more data from a preview after clicking the mouse?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, django-templates

The Database has these fields: id, title, preview, titleWork,  fullDescription, each row.
I can't find a way to show the full database row after clicking on the preview.

I run the loop for showing the previews list contents.
When I click on an image from the list, the console.log is always the last element of the database, but I need the id of the element I clicked to show the others data.
How can I get the id of the element I clicked on, after clicked it?

```
{% for listing in listings %}

    <img class="carousel" id="{{ listing.id}}" onclick="idNumber()" src="{{ 
     listing.preview.url }}" alt="{{ listing.titleWork }}" title="{{ 
     listing.titleWork }}">

        <script>
            function idNumber(){
                idNumb_ = document.getElementById('{{ listing.id | safe}}')
                console.log(idNumb_);
            }
        </script>

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
{% for listing in listings %}
    <img class="carousel" 
         id="{{ listing.id}}" 
         onclick="idNumber({{ listing.id}})" 
         src="{{ listing.preview.url }}" 
         alt="{{ listing.titleWork }}" 
         title="{{ listing.titleWork }}">
{% endfor %}

<script>
    function idNumber(imgId){
        var idNumb_ = document.getElementById(imgId)
        console.log(idNumb_);
    }
</script>
```

Your way hasn't been working because you created `len(listings)` copies of `idNumber` function and each previous one was overridden by the next one

Comment: I think I wrong the way mixing python and js. May I ask clarification? After I got the id I want display the remain information of the DB row for the id of the img I pressed. My intention was to make a request with JS because I can't find a way to make it in Django. My question: is there a way in Django to recognize event click and add a chunk of html, with the remain data of the DB row in the same page? Thank for any help @zvadym

Comment: No. Django gets a request, processes it and returns html page (your template). After that you can't get addition data from django without additional request (it can be ajax).

Comment: I got it. Thanks!